# Package uses conflict: Import-Package: org.springframework.mail.javamail; version="0.0.0"

Tags: osgi

when running my osgi application
i am getting following error:

```
    !ENTRY com.mypackage.commons 4 0 2011-07-06 15:52:21.841
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle could not be resolved. Reason: Package uses conflict: Import-Package: org.springframework.mail.javamail; version="0.0.0"
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1313)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1297)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1068)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:330)
```

please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem solved by using latest version of org.springframework.context.support dependency.

Answer (score 0):

More information is necessary to diagnose the problem. First I recommend running on Apache Felix rather than Equinox – even if only temporarily – because it has better diagnostics for uses-constraints problems. Also try reading my blog posts: http://njbartlett.name/2011/02/09/uses-constraints.html and http://njbartlett.name/2011/03/31/uses-constraints-in-felix.html